# "no overloaded function takes 0 arguments" ao tentar inserir em std::vector

Tags: c++, vector

`bunny` é a classe padrão que possui somente o `bunny(construtor)` e `~bunny(desconstrutor)` padrão.

```
int main()
    {
        vector<bunny> bunnies; // Este usa o construtor padrão.
        bunnies.push_back(); // ERRO! este não pode usar.

        system("Pause");

        return 0;
    }
```

> `Error C2661   'std::vector<bunny,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back': no overloaded function takes 0 arguments.`

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la agora? Veja o [tour] para entender como funciona. Ajudaria muito indicar para todo mundo que a solução foi útil e satisfatória para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

O problema é apenas que está tentando adicionar algo no vetor sem dizer o que. Precisa passar um objeto do tipo `bunny` para o método para ele fazer a adição:

```
bunnies.push_back(bunny());
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/y5kB1U). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/apgpcihx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Vector/PushBack2.cpp).